# What would you expect an entry level pl/sql developer to know?

Tags: plsql

I have an interview coming up for an entry level pl/sql developer job.  I took a class in pl/sql but have not done any projects in pl/sql (other languages yes).  I do know basic sql  (joins subqueries etc), so i am wondering more about specific pl/sql information I should know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say for an entry level position you should have a degree and have taken a course or two on DBs. No experience necessary.

Comment: Agree, don't expect too much on that area. Only keep in mind that they may testify you more on abstract thinking and problem solving capabilities.

Comment: going with what the group feels is the best answer thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree with SP -- if it's entry level, I'd worry more about the person's general knowledge, how well their personality meshes with the organization, and their willingness and aptitude to learn more.

I was doing a telephone interview for a PL/SQL programmer (with no advance warning), and for one of the questions, the candidate said he didn't know, but he was fairly sure the answer was in a given book.  I accepted that as a right answer -- for entry level, admitting that you don't know everything is pretty important.

If you're asking what you should look over before the interview -- I'd say don't study too much, or you might stress out and make a bad impression.  Normally, I'd look see if the person has good skills for the job at hand, but I don't know what they're hiring for ... so if you want to look at something, a good understanding of cursors and sql statement tuning go a long way.

Comment: +1 If they can learn they need not know any PL/SQL for entry level, although they should be working on it.  Reading the Oracle Concepts Guide is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

When interviewing PL/SQL developers for entry position I except:
0. Ability to write simple SQL queries for simple examples (joins, aggregates)
1. Understanding common concepts (triggers, indexes, sequences)
2. Understaning Shcema/User Oracle concepts, grants and synonyms
3. Understanding packages, procedures and functions concepts
4. Ability to write on PL/SQL as normal procedural language (assignments, loops, procdeures, types, etc)

If only 0. and 1. statisfied additional expirience on other big SQL server (Sybase, Microsoft) required. And time to learn after hiring, of course :)

P.S. At period of active entry-level programmers hiring (not now :( ) we require for entry level only degree in CS and ability to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Who is Tom Kyte?

Comment: No humor intended.
Over the last 10 pl/sql programmers I interviewed, exactly one knew who he was.

Comment: not for entry-level, though; a good entry-level programmer won't necessarily know the best sources of info on Oracle, but I'd expect them to learn.

Answer (score 2):

From a technical point of view, I would expect the candidate to be able to create tables, perform simple selects, joins, inserts, updates and deletes.

While interviewing them I would ask questions about working with dates and strings, cursors etc, asking more detailed questions until they couldn't answer. At that point I'd ask them what they would do to find an answer.  With consulting the Oracle help files, asking a team member or web searches being acceptable answers.

Good luck with the interview.

Answer (score 1):

Entry level applicants must demonstrate the following skills:

1. Ability to find the interview site successfully.
2. Can breathe in and out **without** prompting.
3. Demonstrate adequate control of voluntary bodily functions.
4. Successfully spell own name.  Use of items such as driver's license, credit cards, etc, as aids is acceptable.

OK, but seriously...

I'd expect an entry-level applicant to be able to demonstrate some basic familiarity with programming (iteration, loops, subroutines).  Give them a logic test - see how they do.  Have them show that they can write some very basic DML queries.  Polite - no attitude.  Ability to listen.  Ability to talk coherently.  Dress and deportment reasonable for an office setting.  (This means you can have all the tattoos and body piercings you want, and can wear the most eclectic clothing you like - but **I** won't be hiring you).

Comment: 1 and 4 no problem, 3 I am ok with, 2 might be a problem

Comment: I would never work for someone who had an issue with tattoos. Is as stupid as having an issue with a woman who bleaches her hair. Or not hiring due to eyebrow piecing but have no issue with woman having ears pierced. Ignorance.